# i5-4460 or amd fx-8350 for virtual machines (vmware)?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization

I am building a new desktop that will be used as server in my room - it will basically run 24/7 with 20 or 30 vmware virtual machines active (windows xp installed with 512mb ram, 10 gigs of ssd) - these virtual machines will each run multiple active firefox instances.

Apart from that, the machine won't be used for much else - occasional office work but no gaming etc.

The question is, I really dont know which CPU to choose - is here anyone who has enough experience with virtual machines so he can tell me which CPU will be better here, if the 4 core i5 4460 is enough or will the 8 core fx-8350 perform much better?

In the case of i5-4460 I will be going with asrock z97 anniversary motherboard, box cooler and intel integrated graphics.

In the case of amd fx-8350 I will be going with ASUS M5A97 R2.0 motherboard, SAPPHIRE HD 6450 graphics card (I guess it should be enough) and Cooler Master Seidon 120V cooler. The cost of the amd setup will be approximately 80 euro more over the intel i5-4460 setup.

Or a third possibility would be to just buy a i5-4690K and overclock it in case of need (but I dont know if the cores wont be more necessary than the extra power), this option would cost me 70 euro more than the i5-4460 setup.

thanks for help!

Comment: [Intel i5-6400](http://ark.intel.com/products/88185/Intel-Core-i5-6400-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz) and i5-6500 processors were just released with some improvements, may as well take a look at them too.  All of these processors support VT-x and VT-d (or AMD's version).  Don't forget motherboard support can be an issue including with Asus.  (search for Asus motherboard VT-d support)